# Correct procedure to merge two repositories Git

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm trying to understand what's the correct and best way to merge differente istances of the same code into a git repostory.

I have the same code opened on two PCs with different local repositaries. I have modified this code in different aspects (teoretically they won't overlap/create issues with each other) and I want to merge the two codes in one which will contain both edits.

Now, I'm reading about the *rebase* command as well as the *merge* command. It seems that rebase could better fit my use case as the merge is used once more branch on the same repositary need to be merged.

How would I proceed having two different repositary that need to be merged?

The repositaries are both locals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know what you're doing. Following is a bit more advanced way of how I would do this. Pro's, please don't judge hard - there might be simpler ways, of course.

1. Setup git repository on some server. GitHub, for example.
2. Add remote to both local repositories:

   `git remote add github git@github.com:user/repo.git`
3. Push changes from one of your local repositories to remote:

   ```
   git add *
   git commit -m "first commit"
   git --set-upstream-to=github/master
   git push
   ```
4. Commit changes in your other local repository and merge latest code from remote:

   ```
   git add *
   git commit -m "second commit"
   git fetch github
   git merge github/master
   # resolve conflicts
   ```
5. Push changes from other local repository to remote

   ```
   git --set-upstream-to=github/master
   git push
   ```
6. If your PC#1 needs to stay in sync and no changes yet done after PC#2 pushed something, just pull the changes:

   ```
   git pull
   ```

Hope this helps. In general, I would recommend to think about these situations in advance and setup a repository from the very beginning.